# jQueryUI Combobox to avoid external .JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2010

I don't know if it's even possible, but here we go.

Im in a .NET project and we have this .js file that serves the purposes of a flyout menu ([link](http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/menus/flyout.php))
and, on the same page we'd like to have one of these [comboboxes](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)

Thing is, when we add the combobox the button at the right, the one you click in order to get all the possible selections, is just not there. After trying several things we got to know that if we just commentante that flyout .js file the `combobox` works just great. It seems like those javascript codes are messing with each other.

So, can I tell the combobox to not pay attention to that .js file? Is there any workaround to solve this matter?

**EDIT**

I created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bKgQS/1/). As you can see, the combobox is not complete, its button is somehow truncated. (the menu wont get you to anyplace since its tree is gotten from a .html file which is not present in the fiddle.

This other [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HPZ3V/) shows that if we remove the menu.js code, the combobox works propertly

Comment: You should post the relevant code and/or create a [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net) demonstrating your issue.  Also, I see that you are asking for a workaround.  That should be a last resort.  You should ask for help regarding the actual issue, which is getting both the flyout menu and combobox to work simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, maybe I expressed myself the wrong way, for workaround I actually meant to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bKgQS/1/) work, change this line

```
$.fn.menu = function(options){
```

to

```
$.fn.menuFlyout = function(options){
```

[Working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kalyfe/Mz8Rd/)

Explanation: the function menu() is defined twice - once in both libraries you use, flyout and jqueryui.
Rename that function and make sure you use .menuFlyout() when you build your menu.

Comment: Replacing the line works in a way. Now I can see the combobox complete. But adding the combobox js code makes my flyout menu to fail. Maybe I'm not following the .menuFlyout() while building the menu. You mean inside the menu.js code?